# Generic member functions definition

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, member-functions

Is there a way to achieve anything similar to this in C++:

```
template<typename SomeClass>
auto SomeClass::someMemberFunction() { ... }
```

The idea being that if the given member function is declared in a class but not defined, it will get the default definition from this template.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly? Template specialisation is possible along with calling someMemberFunction on SomeClass, provided you have some sort of reference to SomeClass.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am trying to not have to duplicate code over multiple classes. I have several member functions like map, fold, zip that will simply wrap free functions. The issue is that I want to define those member functions once for all of those classes and just add in the declaration inside the classes (they each call a free function variant anyways).

Comment: Maybe you could do it with inheritance, or possibly CRTP?

Comment: You can extract those into a non-template class and inherit the templates from it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The classes are unrelated, so no inheritance.

Comment: @rustyx The templated function works differently based on what class it's called for. For instance something like `someFunc(){someFuncFree(*this);}`. So `*this` cannot be the parent if this were to work correctly.

Comment: @lightxbulb *"`*this` cannot be the parent if this were to work correctly"* You can solve that with CRTP.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I can even solve it with just a template that eats those classes and define the function for that template, but that wasn't exactly the point here. I guess I'll just write a code generator and call it a day.

Comment: Just in case, here's a CRTP-based solution: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ccd14d044ecd3d7

Comment: @holyBlackCat I am aware of this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You can formulate it as an answer btw and I will accept it, since there doesn't seem to be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a general base class as this:

```
class DefaultsAsBase
{   
    public:
    void Bla() { std::cout << "Bla" << std::endl; }
    void Blub() { std::cout << "Blub" << std::endl; }
};  

template < typename T>
class TemplatedOnes: public DefaultsAsBase
{   
    public:
    void Bla() { std::cout << "templated Bla" << std::endl; }
};  

// and the specialized if needed
template <>  
class TemplatedOnes<int>: public DefaultsAsBase
{   
    public:
    void Blub() { std::cout << "Specialized Blub" << std::endl; }
};  

int main()
{
    TemplatedOnes<float> tf; 
    TemplatedOnes<int> ti; 

    tf.Bla();
    tf.Blub();

    ti.Bla();
    ti.Blub();
}
```

If you like, you can add the base class as a parameter to your template, which makes it partly CRTP. Real CRTP have also casts to the deriving class, which is not part of your question, but if you like, you can add it.

```
class DefaultsAsBase
{
    public:
    void Bla() { std::cout << "Bla" << std::endl; }
    void Blub() { std::cout << "Blub" << std::endl; }
};

class OtherDefaultAsBase
{
    void Bla() { std::cout << "Bla other" << std::endl; }
    void Blub() { std::cout << "Blub other" << std::endl; }
};

template < typename T, class CRTP_BASE>
class TemplatedOnes: public CRTP_BASE
{
    public:
    void Bla() { std::cout << "templated Bla" << std::endl; }
};

// and the specialized if needed
template <typename CRTP_BASE>
class TemplatedOnes<int, CRTP_BASE>: public DefaultsAsBase
{
    public:
    void Blub() { std::cout << "Specialized Blub" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    TemplatedOnes<float, DefaultsAsBase> tf;
    TemplatedOnes<int, DefaultsAsBase> ti;
    TemplatedOnes<int, OtherDefaultAsBase> ti2;

    tf.Bla();
    tf.Blub();

    ti.Bla();
    ti.Blub();

    ti2.Bla();
    ti2.Blub();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

On my knowledge, the template type cannot work in this case. You wrote definition of template function, but you need the declaration. Declaration you can write as a one body-one part, NOT of some class members like:

```
class A {
    //some members
};

class A {   //redefinition, not possible "partial class" like in C#
    //the other members
};
```

The solution would be inheritance, but here you don't need templates:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{
    protected:
    Base(){}    
    public: 
    int someMemberFunction() { 
    return 5; 
    }   
};

class A: public Base{
    public:
    int X(){
        return x;   
    }

    void setX(int _x){
        x=_x;
    } 
    private:  
    int x;          
};

int main(){
    A a;
    a.setX(3);
    //Base b;   Base() is protected
    cout <<"a.x="<<a.X()<<endl;
    cout <<"a.someMemberFunction(): "<<a.someMemberFunction()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```